# Problem with WebBrowser Control

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control

Hallo evryone . I have a program hosting .NET WebBrowser Control running on one network drive. After I installed Internet Explorer 9 the control can't be
edited anymore. I suppose that program must be run in compatibility mode but this can't be set for a program on a network drive. The operating system is Windows 7.
I thank in advance if you know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest version of .Net and the control in your application.

Also refer to this question: [Will the IE9 WebBrowser Control Support all of IE9's features, including SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control)

You should probably clarify what you mean by 'the control can't be edited'.

Comment: Thanks. I am already using the latest version of Net. Also I found an article with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001454/internet-explorer-9-rc-stops-my-winforms-webbrowser-control-to-work-in-editing-mo